# String concatenation in Excel VBA failing with run-time error

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation

Why does:

```
sDesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
sTimeStamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hh:nn")
sSuffix = "_1Sheet_" & sDateTimeNow

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    sDesktopPath & ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value & "_1Sheet_" & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

work without problems, BUT:

```
sDesktopPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
sTimeStamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hh:nn")
sSuffix = "_1Sheet_" & sDateTimeNow

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    sDesktopPath & ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value & "_1Sheet_" & sTimeStamp & ".pdf" _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Fails with a runtime error?

[image]

I get the same problem if I use `sSuffix` in place of the `"_1sheet_" & TimeStamp`.

The VBA editor shows the error as being in the last line of the `Export...` statement, but nothing is changing in that line and I can't see anything that is changed before it that would break the syntax.

[image]

Comment: Most probably this bit:  `"yyyymmdd-hh:nn"` .  A folder name can't contain a `:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever something like this happens, try to debug the whole string. Thus:

```
Debug.Print sDesktopPath & ActiveSheet.Range("E3").Value & "_1Sheet_" & sTimeStamp & ".pdf"
```

You will see that the `sTimeStamp` is "illegal", containg `:`. Thus, change the timestamp from:

```
sTimeStamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hh:nn")
```

To:

```
sTimeStamp = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd-hhnn")
```

Comment: Syncronised posting today.  I should start posting those comments as answers - I seem to forget that just because it's a short answer that it's still an answer.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - yup! :)

Comment: DOH!!!! Sooo obvious. Thank you - a real "can't see the wood for the trees" moment - I didn't even want the colon in there!!!

Comment: @FatMonk - it happens. Btw, are you sure it fails with a compilation error and not with a run-time error?

Comment: Yes, that's what really caught me out. The error doesn't show up until the Macro is actually run for the first time but the error says 'file not saved' and the editor says compile error. I'll need to break it again to get the exact details...

Comment: @FatMonk - this is a `run-time error`. `Compile error` is the error that is shown when you press Debug>Compile from the ribbon.

Comment: Just breaking the script again now and the dialog is a runtime error (as you would expect). I've obviously got myself massively confused here as I was sure I saw something that said compile time but that must have been while I was still in the middle of editing things (open `Format(` function, for example). I'll edit the question to correct that as it's misleading.